# Restore HTML form state for cascade controls when hitting F5

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the page http://carmen-rails-demo.herokuapp.com/ there is an example about the Country / State selection that is very common in web forms.

Let's suppose that you select United States and Colorado and after that you hit F5. In this scenario the country code will be remembered, but not the state code, because it's loaded with ajax.

How can I save this state and restore it after a page refresh with F5?

Comment: choices are store in cookie, localStorage or on server. Update accordingly on page load

Comment: You can use localStorage to save the code on ajax success and restore it on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage so save the country and code, something like this:

```
$('.country').change(function() {
   var country = $(this).val();
   localStorage.setItem('country', country);
   $.get('states', {country: country}, function(data) {
      localStorage.setItem('states', JSON.stringify(data));
      var $states = $('.states');
      data.forEach(function(state) {
         $states.append('<option value="'+state.value+'">' +
                        state.value + '</option>');
      });
   });
});
$('.states').change(function() {
   localStorage.setItem('state', $(this).val());
});
var country = localStorage.getItem('country');
if (country) {
    $('.country').val(country);
}
var states = localStorage.getItem('states');
if (states) {
     states = JSON.parse(states);
     var $states = $('.states');
     states.forEach(function(state) {
         $states.append('<option value="'+state.value+'">' +
                        state.value + '</option>');
    });
    var state = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (state) {
        $states.val(state);
    }
}
```